# Need to create a serversocket in java, which listen on only selected IP addresses

Tags: java, serversocket

I'm bit new to networking in java.
I fall into in a situation where I need to create a server socket which will listen on only selected IPs from all the available IPs in the machine.

I have 8 vNICs (interfaces) named from eth0 to eth7 each has its own IP. My server socket should listen only on eth4, eth5, eth6 & eth7.

At the moment I could see an option to listen on a particular IP or any available IPs in a machine. But my requirement is not ANY but only MULTIPLE IPs.

Also, I could see a solution where multiple sockets can be created as one for each IP. Total four sockets in my case.

Is there a better elegant solution?

Comment: I am afraid that you would need to bind a socket to an specific ip address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can listen on one IP address, or all of them. Nothing else.

You will have to create a listening socket per IP address.